# How to build RegExp from strings

Tags: javascript

I have a string and a matching pattern like this :

```
var string = 'stackoverflow Javascript Regex Help';    
var pattern=/(^stackoverflow Javascript)/;
```

I'm looking for a way to reuse my previous pattern without having to rewrite it again. Shortly, I want to add an additional option at the end of my previous pattern (matching a space before splitting)

```
var newString=string.split(pattern+/(.\S*)/);
alert(newString); //Regex Help
```

But this doesn't work.
Is there a way I can accomplish this ?

Thank you for your hep.

Comment: To reuse regex, you can use `RegExp` constructor syntax.

Comment: *"I'm looking for a way to reuse my previous pattern without having to rewrite it again."* — But why? This smells of completely unfounded premature optimization.

Comment: Related: [*How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

Comment: Just create the regular expressions as you need them. Extending the functionality of existing regular expressions is generally unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RegExp` to build a regular expression from a string:

```
var common_pattern = "(^stackoverflow Javascript)";
var extra_pattern = "(.\\S*)"; // need to escape the escape character because the pattern is now a string
var regexp = new RegExp(common_pattern + extra_pattern);

var newString = string.split(regexp);
```

Comment: Note that `common_pattern/pattern` is a **regex** in Q. and **string** here. This is not actually reuse of a _regex_.

Comment: @Marcin what do you mean? I copied your regular expressions, I didn't change them.

Comment: `"(.\S*)"` becomes `"(.S*)"` so that can't be correct. What is your expected output?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you give other example input and output?

Comment: So you just want to trim `"stackoverflow Javascript "`?

Comment: Right .. so how about: `"stackoverflow Javascript Hip Hop Hoop".match(/^stackoverflow Javascript ?(.+)$/)` otuput: `["stackoverflow Javascript Hip Hop Hoop", "Hip Hop Hoop"]`. This will also optionally match the space.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to reuse the pattern it could be done with RegExp's `toString`.

Se [example at JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0xey6kLz/3/).

This example first splits the string using the digit `1`. Then adds the digit `2` to the patter to split at `12`.

Snip:

```
var newPattern = new RegExp(pattern.toString().slice(1,-1) + '2');
```

Regards

Edit:
Updated example to properly handle modifiers.

Comment: NB! As Halcyon I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what you want, so this is simply a *proof of concept*. It's not an exact answer to your specific example/problem.